# High memory usage of network plots with igraph in R

Tags: r, networking, memory, igraph, ram

I am working on building an app to plot relatively large networks (300 nodes and up to 10,000 links) using igraph in R. Ultimately, this app should run as a Shiny app, either in the browser or as a desktop version using Electron.

This problem is that the plotting function `plot(igraphNetwork, ...)` makes the memory shoot up 1GB. Plus, clearing all plots and clearing the environment in RStudio or using `rm(list = ls())` does not bring back the RAM usage to normal. For that, I need to stop the current R session.

Any idea on where the memory leak is ?
Also, how can I render these networks without excessive memory usage ?

Comment: Did you try `gc()` ?

Comment: I did, here's the output :      used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells 1397296 74.7    2262845 120.9  2262845 120.9
Vcells 4105365 31.4   10146329  77.5 10139586  77.4

Comment: Memory usage is still high after the gc command. Some "unknown" data takes up to 800 Mb of RAM.